# CodeIgniter Filling form inputs with table data

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I could get rid of line 29 error by changing result() to result_array(). But the preg_match() string issue still exists.

**Model:**

```
function get_room_details($data_room_type = array() ) {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT rt_id, rt_name FROM room_type ORDER BY rt_name ASC');
    $this->db->query($query);

    if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
            $data_room_type[$row['rt_id']] = $row['rt_name'];
        }
    }
    return $data_room_type;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data_room_type);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line, it is redundant and causes errors:

```
 $this->db->query($query);
```

you have already created result **object** (this var contains result, it is not query string):`$query = $this->db->query('SELECT rt_id, rt_name FROM room_type ORDER BY rt_name ASC');` , and then you pass it as argument to query method - it causing error.